# Will this metropolis chain always converge?

Tags: algorithms, markov-chains, random-walk

Let $G(V, E)$ be a graph and
$\pi$ be a probability distribution on
V. 
Denote by
$J$ the transition matrix of the simple random walk on
$G$.

Let
$P$ be the transition matrix of the Metropolis chain with initial transition matrix
$J$ and desired steady distribution
$\pi$.

Given this information, is it always true that the metropolis chain will converge to $\pi$?
I'm quite confused. Will a periodic graph (like the $4$-cycle) be a counterexample?

Comment: What is a "metropolis chain"? J is alrready given by the random walk on G, which means the entry i,j is the probability of going from vertex i to vertex j given that one goes from i to an adjacent vertex with probability 1/deg(i). In that sense J is determined, and can have only one probability distribution on the vertex set, if it has any at all [there may not be  steady state].

Comment: I'm talking in the context of Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. My question is, will it always converge with the stationary distribution being $\pi$ ?